# How to animate reshuffling of floating divs?

Tags: javascript, css

Looking the following site:

[Here](http://boxavox.com/BoxAVox.aspx)

I am assuming the divs in the center are `float:left`. When you, the divs appear to "animate" resize the window, the "div/boxes" animate to the correct place. How can I replicate this animation? Is this `css` or does it require `javascript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of the page, this is done using the Masonry JavaScript package, that automatically positions elements to optimally use the space available. Here is the documentation on how to use it, either with jQuery or without it: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html. And you can download it from the main page here: http://masonry.desandro.com/.